# How does IIS organize its logs? I have multiple W3SVC* directory

Tags: iis, iis-6

I'm not sure how IIS organize its logs, normally it should all reside in `c:\windows\system32\logfiles\W3SVC\`

But on a Windows 2003 machine, I have both `W3SVC` and `W3SVC436032533`

The former contains:

[image]

And the latter:

[image]

Does any onke know what the number means (after W3SVC)?

And does it mean someone restarted the IIS service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each web site will have it's own W3SVC log directory. You can determine which log directory belongs to which web site by looking at the logging settings for each web site. The log file directory will be displayed in the logging settings.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718126